# File permissions when transferring to another server

Tags: ssh, permissions

If I was to `chmod 777 blah.sh` on server A and then move it to server B, would it retain the permissions, or would it default to some other permissions once it hit server B?

Comment: File permissions are stored in [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends entirely and completely on the method of transfer.

`rsync` will preserve permissions with `-p`, ownership with `-o` (using numeric id only if you pass `--numeric-ids`). `-a` combines `-rlopt`, unless you negate it with `--no-o` or `--no-p`.

`scp` will not normally preserve permissions, but will if you pass `-p`.

`cp` has roughly the same flags (`-p` for permissions, `-a` for everything and recursing).

`tar` has the `-p` flag as well.

`cpio` will always preserve permissions.

Comment: Note that `ftp` will *not*, by default -- unless the FTP client you're using explicitly sets the permissions after uploading, most FTP daemons apply a default umask to uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't since the permissions are attached to users.

However it only takes a simple command to chmod a file so just move it and set the permissions.

Comment: permissions are attached to whom?